# Getting a string representation of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to be able to create a method in a templated class that returns the name of the type subsituted in the template parameter.

eg:

```
template <typename T>
class CPropertyValueT 
{
  std::string GetTypeName()
  {
    return #T;
  }
}
```

This is possible with a preprocessor macro using #, I figured there must be a way with templates.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `typeid(T).name()`, though it will return *decorated* name of the type.

If you're using GCC, then you can use GCC API, declared in`cxxabi.h` header, to demangle the names.

Here is an example ([source](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)):

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>

struct empty { };

template <typename T, int N>
  struct bar { };


int main()
{
  int     status;
  char   *realname;

  // exception classes not in <stdexcept>, thrown by the implementation
  // instead of the user
  std::bad_exception  e;
  realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(e.what(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << e.what() << "\t=> " << realname << "\t: " << status << '\n';
  free(realname);


  // typeid
  bar<empty,17>          u;
  const std::type_info  &ti = typeid(u);

  realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << ti.name() << "\t=> " << realname << "\t: " << status << '\n';
  free(realname);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  St13bad_exception       => std::bad_exception   : 0
  3barI5emptyLi17EE       => bar<empty, 17>       : 0
```

Another interesting link that describe demangling in GCC and Microsoft VC++:

- [C++ Name Mangling/Demangling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)

Comment: Good answer, this is the best one can do. However, it is noteworthy that `name()` isn't mandated to return anything meaningful by the standard, so it's a QOI issue.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Yes. BTW, I added more stuffs to my answer.