# Getting String Representation of a Template Parameter at Compilation Time

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static-variables

#### TL;DR

How do I initialize a static template variable that will have a different value for each class that inherits from it?

#### Not TL;DR

I have the following code in my project, that is intended to identify the class created with a template parameter, to make sure no one else creates it (in a different part of the code, not represented here):

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
   ... some other code and methods ...   
   
   virtual const char* getId() 
   {
      return idString;
   }

   static const char* const idString;
};
```

I would like to initialize idString, so as we know and saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094045/initialize-a-static-const-member-with-a-template-argument) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026555/how-to-define-a-static-const-variable-of-a-template-class), I want to initialize the variable in the header file underneath the class definition, where the above class declaration is located:

```
template <typename T>
const char* const idString = strcat("foo::", #T);
```

or something like that, because this does not compile.
This is done so that the following code:

```
class bar : public foo<S>
{
   ...some other code...
   
   const char* getId()
   {
      return idString;
   }

   static const char* const idString;
};
```

will generate `"foo<S>"` when `getId()` is called with a `bar` class instance and `"foo<T>"` when the base class `getId()` is called, by **hiding** the const variable `idString` of `foo` (this is, of course, not an override).

Thing is, `strcat` is not a something the compiler can calculate at run time, so this doesn't work well. Currently, the only thing that will work, but has backward compatibility issues is adding a `const char*` class parameter to the `foo` class definition, but than each instance of `foo<P>` will have to beconme `foo<P, "foo::P">` manually, and will break previous code uses.

I have read a few solutions that looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545377/getting-a-string-representation-of-a-template-parameter) which rely on RTTI, but this isn't the case here.

Thought of using a `macro` for this, since macros are pre-compilation and can "know" the string representation from the text written, but can't get the syntax properly. Any other suggestions will be incredible! Thank you.

Comment: Your question is wage and I personally don't understand what is the problem. Please edit your question and use easier language to describe the situation.

Comment: Also please note that you can never instantiate a template like ```foo<P, "foo::P">``` because ```"foo::p"``` is not valid parameter for the template and string literals can never be used for this purpose .

Comment: You have to rely on RTTI. There is no other way to do it.

Comment: @newbie you're right about the `"foo::P"` remark, that was actually psuedo-code for saying I will add a template parameter. About the question being not understandable - it's a complex question, so a complex explanation was unfortunately needed, sorry about that. I really put an effort in describing the situation.

Comment: I added somewhat of a TL;DR section to clarify my question perhaps, but it lacks some cases that answering the TL;DR question will not answer my bigger question

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522794/2752075) answer your question?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat actually it does, but I did find a simpler way and marked it as an answer, but your reference would work on any project that has C++11 and above only, while I don't (I didn't write that on purpose because I didn't want to limit the answer to not using `constexpr`)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, just opened a namespace in the inherited class's header file and initialized the static member there:

```
bar.h:

namespace foo
{
    const char* const foo<bar>::idString = "foo<bar>";
}
```

and for other bars that didn't implement this they get a default value defined in `foo`'s class.